# Updating a specific package in a legacy system which has deprecated libs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, pipenv

I have a pipfile which has following packages

```
p1 = "*"
p2 = "==1.2.3"
p3 = "*"
```

now, I want to update `p3` from `*` to let say version `5.2` (latest). I can do that by doing `pipenv install p3==5.2`. The problem is that our company used their own repo for in-house libraries (`p1` and `p2`) and those are now gone. (legacy system lots of red-tape around).

Is there a way to ask `pip` to just updated `p3` without touching other libs?

I tried using `pipenv install p3==5.2 --keep-outdated` but it got errored out on those libraries.

Another approach that i tried was to remove all such libraries and updated the pipfile/pipfile.lock. then copied the `sha` for only `p3` library into my git commit. This gave me error that `pipfile` is outofdate. (i assume this happened because pipfile meta sha didn't match the actual content of the file).